# Does cron job persist/run again if the python script fails?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cron

I have a remote cron job that scrapes data using selenium every 30 minutes. Roughly 1 in 10 times the selenium script fails. When the script fails, I get an error output instead (various selenium error messages). Does this cause the cron job to stop? Shouldn't crontab try to run the script again in 30 minutes?

After a failed attempt, when I type `crontab -l`, it still shows my cron job.

How do I ensure that the crontab tries again in 30 minutes?

Comment: Have you tried waiting and seeing the if cron job persists? Maybe setting a shorter duration for testing purposes?

Comment: To answer your question, the error came from the python file - either a Selenium error or an issue with loading the page. See my answer below for how I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Who is sending the error output?  If it's the cron daemon, then your job should be dead; if the selenium process itself is sending the mail, then it may still be running, and stuck.

Comment: See both my responses above. Thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: The website I was scraping was sophisticated enough to find out I was using selenium because cron was running the job every 30 minutes on the dot. So they flagged my VM's IP address after the 4-5th attempt.

My solution was simple: add randomness to the interval with which I scrapped the website using random.uniform and time.sleep - now I have no issues scraping.